# Let all apps read my external SD card

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, vanilla-android

I have an external SD card, and I want to keep it that way.
I have lots of files on it sorted how I prefer. But now all my apps that I've saved data from or use to open files can't access the external SD card.

I've gone to app permissions and made sure they have storage. I just want them to have full access to my SD card, because, well, it's my SD card.

TitaniumBackup won't backup to it's folder anymore, says no space even though there are gigs free. My camera app won't save to the external dir I've put my pictures in. My music app won't give me a list of the files in the directory where I've sorted my music. Is there any way to just force MM to just let those apps have full access to my SD card?
I can browse the SD card with ESExplorer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes CyanogenMOD messes with the SD card paths after rooting. If that is the case, you will need to use a terminal emulator to correct the path to /sdcard/external_sd

Make the external_sd folder in your SD card first. Then through the emulator use the command

su

mount -o bind your_current_path_as_per_es_explorer /sdcard/external_sd